# deselectRowAtIndexPath not doing anything

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been writing a small Swift app.
I'm now using a tableview and try to select a row, change an image and deselect the row.

My custom `UITableViewCell` class looks like this:

```
class SelectFriendTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var friendNameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var friendSelectedImage: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

And my `TableViewController` has these functions:

Building the cells:

```
//Build the cell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SelectFriend", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SelectFriendTableViewCell

    //Default image is unselected
    cell.friendSelectedImage.image = UIImage(named: "unselected")
    //Get the label text
    cell.friendNameLabel.text = friendList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Do stuff when cell is selected (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`)

```
 //Cell was selected
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SelectFriend", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SelectFriendTableViewCell

    //Check wheter the cell is or not selected
    if(cell.friendSelectedImage.image == UIImage(named: "unselected"))
    {
        //if it's unselected, select it and add the user to the invited list
        cell.friendSelectedImage.image = UIImage(named: "selected")
        //Add to the invited list, the label can't be null
        invitedList += [cell.friendNameLabel.text!]
    }

    else if(cell.friendSelectedImage.image == UIImage(named: "selected"))
    {
        //if it's selected, unselect it and remove the user from the invited list
        cell.friendSelectedImage.image = UIImage(named: "unselected")
        //Find the invited in the array and remove it
        for(var i=0; i < invitedList.count; i++)
        {
            if(invitedList[i] == cell.friendNameLabel.text!)
            {
                invitedList.removeAtIndex(i)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("error geting image")
    }

    //Trying to deselect the row, doesn't seem to be working
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
}
```

What I'm seeing:

[image: Didn't select any cells]

[image: Cell was selected]

There's also the problem that the label is disappearing.

Comment: What do you want the `deselect` to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier** did not get the previous cell, you should use **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //get the cell,
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SelectFriendTableViewCell
    //do some work
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code with no explanation. Update your answer by explaining what was wrong and how your answer solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks! This worked :)
So? i'm building the cell again? What's happening here?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  use to create cell, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` use to accessing a cell. more detail you can view [AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW64)

Comment: Seems like I was creating another cell object instead of accessing the one I had. "cellForRowAtIndexPath" is used to associate a created cell to an indexPath. And, with the cell already created I can now access it via cellForRowAtIndexPath and run the code I wanted to.